# Display city names in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'd like to display all city names on a tableview based on what the user types in a searchBar. 
For example if the user types "New York" inside the searchBar I want to be displayed all the results the API gives me. 
I'm using an API which returns JSON data.

Right now I'm using this delegate methods:

```
extension searchViewController : UISearchBarDelegate{

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        RequestAPI.queryCities(cityNameString: searchBar.text!) { (cities) in
        for iterator  in 0...cities.geonames.count-1 {
            self.citiesQueried.append(cities.geonames[iterator])
        }
    }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("cancel button clicked")
    self.citiesQueried.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

citiesQueried is an array that I declared empty before in the viewController an has the task of collecting all the data resulted from the API request.

These are the delegate methods of UITableView:

```
extension searchViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return citiesQueried.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCityTableViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.citiesQueried[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
}
```

The problem is that sometime it works and sometime it doesn't and I need to press 2 times the search button in order to see the cities displayed on the tableView. 
I think something is missing, I hope some of you could give me a suggestion on how to solve this issue

Comment: Reload your tableView on success from API.

Comment: You need to call `reloadData` inside the completion handler closure for `queryCities`, and remember to dispatch it onto the main queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reload the table view inside the completion handler of the asynchronous task

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    RequestAPI.queryCities(cityNameString: searchBar.text!) { (cities) in
        for iterator  in 0..<cities.geonames.count {
            self.citiesQueried.append(cities.geonames[iterator])
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Side note:

The name `cities` implies to be an array but it seems to be a single object. Then the `for` loop is not needed and name the parameter in singular form

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    RequestAPI.queryCities(cityNameString: searchBar.text!) { city in          
        self.citiesQueried = city.geonames         
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this suggestion helped me a lot, yes actually cities is not an array but has one only variable that is an array of cities, so I decided to call it cities

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't know why the searchBarCancelButtonClicked delegate method doesn't work, I'd like to delete all the cities queried and reload the tableView but it doesn't seem to be responsive at user inputs at all

Comment: yes the method is called and is the snippet I included in my question, but I don't know why when I press cancel button nothing happens, not even the print() inside the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Reload tableView after success from API, like below:

```
RequestAPI.queryCities(cityNameString: searchBar.text!) { (cities) in
         for iterator  in 0...cities.geonames.count-1 {
            self.citiesQueried.append(cities.geonames[iterator])
         }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```